# Add '\n' after a specific number of delimiters

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk, cut

How can I add a `\n` after each four `;` delimiter in a CSV file (with bash)?

Input file sample:

```
aaaa;bbbbbb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;ffff;gggg;hhhh;iii;jjjj;kkkk;llll;
```

Output needed :

```
aaaa;bbbbbb;cccc;ddddd
eeee;ffff;gggg;hhhh
iii;jjjj;kkkk;llll
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using (GNU) `sed`:

```
... | sed -r 's/([^;]*;){4}/&\n/g'
```

`[^;]*;` matches a sequence of characters that are not semicolons followed by a semicolon.

`(...){4}` matches 4 times the expression inside the parentheses.

`&` in the replacement is the whole match that was found.

`\n` is a newline character.

The modifier `g` make `sed` replace all matches in each input line instead of just the first match per line.

Comment: Could you explain the regexp you used please?

Answer (score 2):

Read each line into an array, then print 4 groups at a time with `printf` until the line is exhausted.

```
while IFS=';' read -a line; do
    printf '%s;%s;%s;%s\n' "${line[@]}"
done < input.txt
```

Comment: +1, but note that this will misbehave if there are any empty fields. (To handle that case, I think you'd need to use `-d ';'` instead of `IFS=';'`, and adjust your logic accordingly.)

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's/;/++$i % 4 ? ";" : "\n"/ge; chomp'
```

Only works if the number of fields is divisible by four.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/;/\n/4;/./P;D' file
```