# How do you break an array in groups of n

Tags: arrays, bash

This is similar to [Add '\n' after a specific number of delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239636/add-n-after-a-specific-number-of-delimiters/18239734#18239734), however, lets assume the number if elements in a group is programmable.

we have:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj,kkk,lll,mmm
g=4
```

we want

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
eee,fff,ggg,hhh
iii,jjj,kkk,lll
mmm
```

How do we accomplish this with bash?

I have tried a number of options.  Here's the latest failure (tmp[] is the array):

```
for e in ${tmp[@]}; do 
  for i in $(eval echo "{0..$groupsof}"); do 
    foo[$i]=$e; 
  done
done
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use substring expansion. `"${array[@]:offset:length}"` gets you `length` elements starting at `offset`:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm)
g=4

for((i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; i+=g))
do
  part=( "${array[@]:i:g}" )
  echo "Elements in this group: ${part[*]}"
done
```

Comment: +1: Though you might want to add `IFS=,` inside the loop to match the output.

Answer (score 3):

```
kent$  array=(aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm)

kent$  echo "${array[@]}"|xargs -n4                               
aaa bbb ccc ddd
eee fff ggg hhh
iii jjj kkk lll
mmm
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
echo aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj,kkk,lll,mmm | sed 's/,/,\n/g' | paste -d "" $(yes - | head -4 | paste -s) | sed 's/,$//g'
```