# Print Array in batches Shell script

Tags: arrays, shell, unix

I have a huge array and I am trying to print the values in batches.

I tried doing it by creating counters but I am unable to proceed beyond it .

```
batchsize=10
start=0
end=$batchsize
count=`expr ${#arr[@]} / $batchsize`
echo $count
remainder=`expr ${#arr[@]} % $batchsize`
echo $remainder
counter=0
```

I basically want 10 records from array to come in below format in every loop

```
 Total Size = 1000000;
 permissibleCars = ["Array1","Array2",...."Array10"]
  { abc
         cde
    xu=yz
  }
```

I tried doing it using for loop but it is not going anywhere due to my lack of expertise

```
for i in "$count"
  do 
   echo "counter : $counter"
    for j in "${arr[@]}"
     do   
      { echo "$j"
      }
     start=$start + $batchsize
     end=$end + $batchsize
   done 
if [$remainder!=0];then
end=$end - $batchsize + $remainder
  for i in "$counter"
  do 
   do     
    { echo "$i"
   }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747612/how-do-you-break-an-array-in-groups-of-n). `g` is your batchsize.

Comment: Thanks. This works fine only that there is no  "," between the arrays .

Comment: Was able to fix it using IFS .. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Answer available here [Batch Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747612/how-do-you-break-an-array-in-groups-of-n)