# Segment arrays into n groups with order preserved

Tags: arrays, permutation

My question is similar to [how-do-you-break-an-array-in-groups-of-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747612/how-do-you-break-an-array-in-groups-of-n).

There an array:

> ```
> aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj,kkk,lll,mmm
> ```

is segmented into 3 arrays containing 4 elements and 1 array with 1 element to get an output of:

> ```
> aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
> eee,fff,ggg,hhh
> iii,jjj,kkk,lll
> mmm
> ```

using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm)
g=4
for((i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; i+=g))
    do
    part=( "${array[@]:i:g}" )
    echo "Elements in this group: ${part[*]}"
done
```

I would be grateful for unix-based approaches on how to segment the array to get the following output (i.e. 10 arrays), and also be able to define an arbitrary number of elements in an array (i.e. like the value of g in the above script):

> ```
> aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
> bbb,ccc,ddd,eee
> ccc,ddd,eee,fff
> ddd,eee,fff,ggg
> eee,fff,ggg,hhh
> fff,ggg,hhh,iii
> ggg,hhh,iii,jjj
> hhh,iii,jjj.kkk
> iii,jjj,kkk,lll
> jjj,kkk,lll,mmm
> ```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can only do in Python. You will have to convert into c++.

Snippet:

```
listA = 'aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii','jjj','kkk','lll','mmm'

def matrix_4x4(m,n, sep):
    print( "\n".join(map("{}".format(sep).join, (m[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(m), n))))) 
matrix_4x4(listA, 4, ",")
```

Output:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
eee,fff,ggg,hhh
iii,jjj,kkk,lll
mmm
```

Comment: Hi toyota supra, thank you for your effort, but your snippet does not produce the desired output.  It gives the same output as the nix snippet i already referenced in my question.

Comment: Did you convert to c++?